# persistent cookie timeout after custom time and it is not persistence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, authentication

i have set authentication cookie same below:

> FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(member.UserName, member.RememberMe);

and in web.config:

> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>   <forms loginUrl="~/Login"  timeout="2" slidingExpiration="true"/>
> </authentication>
> ```

when remember is true or false , the result is not different , and user log out after 2 minute. where is my problem?
Thanks

Comment: are you using sessionState in web config with timeout="2"

Comment: @akhlesh no,it doesn't have it. i have this code in global.asax: " void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
            SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }"

Answer (score 0):

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(member.UserName, member.RememberMe);
```

if member.RememberMe is **false** then cookie will expire either on timeout or when user closes browser.

if  member.RememberMe is **true** then cookie will expire only on timeout(it doesn't matter its persistent or not).

But if you want to increase timeout for persistent cookies then you can do like this:-

```
var timeOut = member.RememberMe ? DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20) : DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
var fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, member.UserName, DateTime.Now,timeOut, member.RememberMe, member.UserName);
string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat);
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket) { Expires = fat.Expiration });
```